# 【monaco-editor】How to register more than one inlineCompletionsProvider in editor

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, editor, monaco-editor

I have registerd two providers in the editor, I need to press 'Enter' key to call the provider1, and press 'Space' key to call the provider2.
And I used
`monacoEditor. trigger ('', 'editor. action. inline Suggest. trigger', '')`
to activate. But Both providers will trigger, the mehtod provideInlineCompletions will be triggered,I cannot distinguish which provider was specifically called. Monaco also did not provide relevant parameters for judgment, What I want is to be able to distinguish between these two providers and call them separately.

I want to distinguish between these two providers and call them separately